# Github - Different search results from the web vs the API

Tags: github, octokit-js

I am using the Octokit.js library and I get different results from the search method vs when I use the web UI at https://github.com/search. The query I am running is:

```
state:open is:pr review-requested:myusername
```

The web UI returns all the PRs where I am the reviewer but the library only returns one of those PRs. What could be the issue? something to do with permission? The token that is being used was fetched through the OAuth flow of a Github App